# Passing array from one template to another in magento2

Tags: magento2, array

I have used two template for homepage(template inside another template)
I am calling product template inside category template.
Now my case scenario is

> **1. I am declaring one array in category template**
>
> **2. I want to pass this empty array to product template.**
>
> **3. Add elements in that array in product template.**
>
> **4. Pass the array back to category template.**

**How can i do that.**

**Let me know if there is any confusion.**

Comment: You can add these templates inside one block and then you can write your logic in a single block class, You can access the function from both the templates.

Comment: Can u give me example through code?

Comment: Can you tell me your templates rendering code So that I can have an idea what you actually want to do?

Comment: Is there any way to access variable declared in one phtml file into another?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's worked for me.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setKey('test')->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::test.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

to get value use

```
echo $this->getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your actual requirement, in first phtml file add below code :

```
$arr=array(23,4); 

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Modulename\Block\Display")->setData('var1', $arr)->setTemplate("Vendor_Modulename::test2.phtml")->toHtml();
```

In second phtml i.e. test2.phtml add

```
$catIds=$block->getData("var1"); 

$arr=array(); 

foreach($catIds as $catId){ 
    $_productCollection=$block->setCustomValue($catId); 

        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){ 
                $currentId=$_product->getId(); 
                if (!in_array($currentId, $arr)){ 
                        echo $_product->getData("name");echo "<br/>"; 
                    } 
                $arr[]=$_product->getId(); 
        } 

}
```

In `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Display.php` add below code:

```
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
         $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function setCustomValue($value) 
    { 
        $categoryId = $value; 
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create(); 
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category); 
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED); 
        return $collection; 
    }
```

Comment: what if i want to fetch this value in another phtml?

Comment: To fetch value in phtml, use this code:
print_r($block->getData("var1"));

Comment: Thanx. This worked. now how can i append more values in this array in other phtml itself. inshort how can i append in this $block->getData("var1")

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass this value again to another phtml? If so, then you can directly pass the variable to required phtml

Comment: i want to append more elements in this array and then again pass this array back to the first phtml file

Comment: Did you get my query?

Comment: I got your point, are you modifying the value in second phtml & again sending in the first phtml? But as per my view, this way is not proper. can you tell me your exact requirement, so that I call tell you further?

Comment: basically i am designing homepage. In that i am displaying category image and product for that particular category. For e.g
First Category 1 image,
Below that 6 products of category 1. After that category 2 image, below that 6 products of category 2. Now the scenario is there may be some product which belongs to both category  1 and category 2 and i dnt want to repeat that image in homepage. basically product once displayed for category 1 should not be again displayed for category 2

Comment: I have made one template for category image inside that i am calling block for displaying products

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97132/discussion-between-mona-mehta-and-nafisa).